# Visitor and composite pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm struggling with in combining the visitor and the composite patterns in Java.

I have an Element interface for the Composite. It only has the accept method.

I have an abstract class Composite to handle the child management function(add, remove and getChild). I would like to define the acccept method in the compiste class to avoid having to do it in each subclass. Is there a way to do that?

```
public abstract class Composite implements Element {

    protected List<Element> elements;

    public Composite() {
        elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
    }

    public void add(Element e) {
     elements.add(e);   
    }

    public void remove(Element e) {
        elements.remove(e);
    }

    public Element getChild(int i) {
        return elements.get(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see why not. What is your problem exactly? Just implement `accept()` in `Composite`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this what you are looking for?

```
public abstract class Composite implements Element {

    protected List<Element> elements;

    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        for(Element element: elements) {
            element.accept(visitor);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Kinda. I was going for a similar solution but with, the composite subclasses is not visited. And it has to be visited before going through its children. Do I have to override the accept method in each subclass and do visitor.visit(this); super.accept(visitor);

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean when you say the subclass is not visited? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Composite is an abstract class so you can't do visitor.visit(this) in the accept method of hte abstract class.

Comment: Alright, I got it now ;-) Could have seen it myself but next time include something like this in your question. Better to have the problem explicitly. I'm thinking about it now.